# Facebook Developer- Messenger- add multiple webhooks for a single facebook page

Tags: facebook, heroku, dialogflow-es, facebook-webhooks

I am trying to build a chatbot using Facebook developer platform. I want my bot to respond differently under different scenarios. So, basically I have my standard bot implementation on Heroku server. I want to bring in api.ai into my bot so as to leverage the kind of functionalities api.ai offers.

To bring in api.ai, I need to configure webhook in my Facebook app. As my Facebook app is already subscribed to Heroku, I don't see an option to add another webhook. Is there a way to subscribe my app on Facebook to multiple webhooks?

If not, is there any way to integrate api.ai using api calls from my heroku server?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's likely you'd probably just forward them along to the next endpoint. Have your server be the frontend, and forward requests from your server to the next webhook if needed.